# Pygame zooming screen

Tags: python, pygame, camera, zooming

im writing a game right now with 32x32 textures, i have a problem because my screen window is too small, is there any solution? Can i "zoom" my whole game?[image]

Now it looks like this and exactly what i want is to make whole screen bigger and zoom to see only like 5% of map.

Of course, if i make my screen bigger it not gonna fix my problem.
Maybe i should add another camera or something?
[image]

I think I made myself quite clear.
Thanks!

Comment: *"I think I made myself quite clear. "* - No you have not. What is the question? What have you tried so far? Where do you struggle? Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can definitely zoom as you are saying.

```py
screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(display, (int(width), int(height)))
```

You can resize the screen:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT),pygame.RESIZABLE)
def resize(event):
    global WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT
    if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
        WINDOWWIDTH = event.size[0]
        WINDOWHEIGHT = event.size[1]
        return pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

And have the display the actual size you want to draw to:

```py
display = pygame.Surface((300,200))
```

However, scaling surfaces is really bad as pixel art isn't great at scaling. An alternative would be a camera or switching off of pygame which would make everything you are trying to do way less complicated. I would recommend [rubato](https://rubato.app/) for a start. It will do all this work for you, and you can decide how big you want your actual grid (display) to be with one variable.

Good luck! Feel free to comment if you want any extra help.

Answer (score -1):

One way you can fix this is by shrinking the size of the screen itself:

```
#you can adjust the width and height in game until it seems the right fit
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
```

And if you want, you can set the window to Fullscreen:

```
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```